# Only before VAT price is displayed

Tags: price, ce-1.9.0.1, tax

My website displays price before VAT only no matter what I change in the price display settings.  The VAT is not added until the checkout.  I want to show both before and after VAT prices on the website, whats going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Go to magento -> configuration -> sales -> Tax -> there are options to display tax inculude or exclude on product page, cart page etc.